# split csv field into multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have a table with 200,000 rows of data. The field attendees has been populated in a csv format; split with a comma delimiter. I would like split this field into up to 7 different columns, labelled Field1, Field2 etc.

### Example data:

```
pkEventBooking  Attendees
166935          p1193,c21867,c21827,c21963,c18069,c19222,
195867          p1193,c21827,c22572,c19222,c22573,c21963,c18069,
```

### New Format

```
pkEventBooking   Field1   Field2   Field3    Field 4   Field5   Field6  Field7
166935           p1193    c21867   c21827    c21963    c18069   c19222
195867           p1193    c21827   c22572    c19222    c22573   c21963  c18069,
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

I would be inclined to export the data in a comma-delimited format and re-import it.  With this volume of data, you can do the followiong:

1. Run `select * from example` or `select pkEventBooking + ',' + Attendees`
2. Copy the data into Excel
3. Go to the "Data" ribbon and choose "text to columns"
4. Save out as a file
5. Import the file with a tab delimiter

By the way, I would really suggest that you structure the data to have two columns:

- pkEventBooks
- Attendee

And then have multiple columns for that.

You can do this directly in the database:

```
insert into EventAttendees(EventBookId, Attendee)
    select t.EventBookId, ss.Attendee
    from table t cross apply
         dbo.SplitString(Attendees) as ss(Attendee);
```

You can google "SQL Server splitstring" to get a definition of such a function.

Answer (score 0):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (pkEventBooking INT,  Attendees NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(166935 , 'p1193,c21867,c21827,c21963,c18069,c19222'),
(195867 , 'p1193,c21827,c22572,c19222,c22573,c21963,c18069')
```

### Query

```
;WITH Split_Names (pkEventBooking, Attendees)
AS
(
 SELECT pkEventBooking,
       CONVERT(XML,'<Attendees><Attendee>'  
   + REPLACE(Attendees,',', '</Attendee><Attendee>') + '</Attendee></Attendees>') AS Attendees
 FROM @Table
)

 SELECT pkEventBooking,      
 Attendees.value('/Attendees[1]/Attendee[1]','varchar(100)') AS Attendees1,    
  Attendees.value('/Attendees[1]/Attendee[2]','varchar(100)') AS Attendees2,
   Attendees.value('/Attendees[1]/Attendee[3]','varchar(100)') AS Attendees3,
    Attendees.value('/Attendees[1]/Attendee[4]','varchar(100)') AS Attendees4,
     Attendees.value('/Attendees[1]/Attendee[5]','varchar(100)') AS Attendees5,
      Attendees.value('/Attendees[1]/Attendee[6]','varchar(100)') AS Attendees6,
       Attendees.value('/Attendees[1]/Attendee[7]','varchar(100)') AS Attendees7
 FROM Split_Names
```

### Result

```
╔════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ Value  ║ Attendees1 ║ Attendees2 ║ Attendees3 ║ Attendees4 ║ Attendees5 ║ Attendees6 ║ Attendees7 ║
╠════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ 166935 ║ p1193      ║ c21867     ║ c21827     ║ c21963     ║ c18069     ║ c19222     ║ NULL       ║
║ 195867 ║ p1193      ║ c21827     ║ c22572     ║ c19222     ║ c22573     ║ c21963     ║ c18069     ║
╚════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Excellent piece of code, I just needed to 'SET ARITHABORT ON', now works a treat. Well Done !!

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Data:**

```
    DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (pkEventBooking INT,  Attendees NVARCHAR(MAX))
    INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
    (166935 , 'p1193,c21867,c21827,c21963,c18069,c19222'),
    (195867 , 'p1193,c21827,c22572,c19222,c22573,c21963,c18069')
```

**Query:**

```
  SELECT 
       pkEventBooking,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SplitIndex = 1 THEN Value END) AS Column1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SplitIndex = 2 THEN Value END) AS Column2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SplitIndex = 3 THEN Value END) AS Column3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SplitIndex = 4 THEN Value END) AS Column4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SplitIndex = 5 THEN Value END) AS Column5,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SplitIndex = 6 THEN Value END) AS Column6,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SplitIndex = 7 THEN Value END) AS Column7
  FROM (
       SELECT 
          pkEventBooking,
          Value,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pkEventBooking 
                 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS SplitIndex
       FROM @TABLE
       CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Attendees, ',')
    ) AS T
    GROUP BY pkEventBooking;
```

[image: SQL Result]

Answer (score 0):

Just another option is to use a bit of JSON in concert with a `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
 Select A.[pkEventBooking]
       ,Pos1 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
       ,Pos2 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
       ,Pos3 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
       ,Pos4 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]')
       ,Pos5 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[4]')
       ,Pos6 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[5]')
       ,Pos7 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[6]')
 From  YourTable A
Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape([Attendees],'json'),',','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
```

**Results**

[image]